# Is $\mathbb{R}$ an algebraic extension of some proper subfield?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Is there a (proper) subfield $K$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{R}$ is an algebraic extension of $K$?

From this question, [Is there a proper subfield $K\subset \mathbb R$ such that $[\mathbb R:K]$ is finite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211582/is-there-a-proper-subfield-k-subset-mathbb-r-such-that-mathbb-rk-is-fin), it is clear that for such an $K$, $[\mathbb{R}:K]=\infty$.

This question seems to be non-trivial, and I suspect any existence result will be non-constructive. Any references will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by $F$?

Comment: sorry, meant $K$

Comment: Can't one just do the following? Let $S$ be a real transcendence basis for $\Bbb C$ over $\bar{\mathbb Q}$ and take $\mathbb Q(S)$

Comment: Just to be clear, you are asking whether or not there is a constructive or axiom of choice-free construction that would give that, or is one involving choice fine? If it's the latter, you can do as PVAL suggests in much the same way as you find a basis for ${\bf R}$ over ${\bf Q}$.

Comment: If $K$ is a maximal subfield of $\mathbb R$ not containing $\sqrt2$ (such as exists by Zorn's lemma), isn't every element of $\mathbb R$ algebraic over $K$?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426842/are-the-real-numbers-a-nontrivial-simple-extension-of-another-field

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to have at least one actual answer to the question, I'll convert the comment by PVAL to an answer.

Using Zorn's lemma there exists a transcendence basis $B$ of $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q$: a maximal algebraically independent (over $\Bbb Q$) set of real numbers. Then $\Bbb Q(B)$ is a subfield of $\Bbb R$, and by maximality every element of $\Bbb R$ is algebraic over $\Bbb Q(B)$. So $\Bbb R/\Bbb Q(B)$ is an algebraic extension.

Comment: Why is $\mathbb{Q}(B)$ a proper subfield of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Amudhan: Because $\Bbb Q(B)$ is a purely transcendental extension of $\Bbb Q$, so it contains no irrational algebraic (over$~\Bbb Q)$ elements such as $\sqrt{13}$.